# Little bit Identical but paraphased content in a Tool Site. Is this a good idea in SEO wise?

Tags: seo, google-adsense, thin-content

I have a online tool site where provides many conversion tools. such as JPG to PNG, JPG to PDF, JPG to BMP, PNG to JPG etc..
So I have a plan to integrate my adsense account with this site. But to avoid thin content penalty Right below the tool at every page I added a descrtion.
My structure is

eg:

```
Title : JPG to PNG Converter
[Tool Goes Here]

JPG file format
[description 500 words]

PNG File format
[description 500 words]
```

---

So when the tool change to JPG to BMP converter. Again

```
JPG file format
[description 500 words]

BMP File format
[description 500 words]
```

As you can see I can comeup with many pairs. But when I do I want to consider about unique content. In here  JPG file format's description should be unique. Otherwise google hit me with the duplicate penalty.
To overcome this I use chatGPT to generate those descriptions. Now everything seems different. But every page will have same type of description.

The whole point of using a description is to rank higher on Google. Is my approach good in SEO-wise?  What can I do to stay out of trouble? Remember this is not a blog.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your descriptions of each file format in static files, and embed them using iframes:

```
<iframe src="static/about-jpeg.html" style="border:none" ></iframe>
<iframe src="static/about-png.html" style="border:none"></iframe>
<iframe src="static/about-bmp.html" style="border:none"></iframe>
```

This way, search engines won't have to read and carve multiple times the same descriptions and should limit the risk of duplicate content.

In the header of the static pages, tell the search engines if they should index them or not using a meta tag: `<meta name="robots" content="..." />`

**Example**

One site of mines had some content that was nonsense to index.
The pages now display this content in a iframe, which is stored in a static page.
In my case, I ask search engines to not index this static content:

```
<html>
  <head>
    (...)
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
  </head>
</html>
```

but the directives may be different for your site, depending on your needs.

**Last word**

Personally, I would not artificially generate some almost identical content. Algorithms from search engines do improve year after year and I believe trying to cheat is a waste of time.
Focus on adding real value for your visitors, and it should pay off in the long run.

Comment: Adsense cant see what inside iframes and they are not encouraging them. https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/149874717/can-we-use-iframe-in-my-website-with-google-adsense?hl=en